# Possible value of $( p + q )$.

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let $ g : \Bbb R \to ( - \infty, - 1]$ be the function defined as 
$$g(x) = ( pq + 2p - q - 2 ) x^5 -( p^3 - 2p + 1 ) x^3 + ( p^2 - 2p - 3 ) x^2 + ( p^2 + 2q )x - 5$$
where $p,q \in \Bbb R$. If $g(x)$ is surjective, then the possible value of $( p + q )$ is (are)

Comment: Why do you say $g(x)$ maps to $(-\infty, -1]$?   If the coefficient of $x^5$ is non-zero then it is surjective onto all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Note:  if you are trying to say that $p,q$ are such that the image of $g(x)$ is contained in this set, then you should say that explicitly.

Comment: Voting to close the question.  If you can, please edit your post for clarity and to indicate what attempts you have made.

Comment: On looking at your previous questions why does it seem that these questions are from some sort of exam.  Can please name the the exam from which you have asked these questions.

Comment: @lulu I think you are being a little unfair on the question. Its whole point is that you have to pick particular $p=1,q=3.5$ in order to satisfy the requirement that the function has a maximum value of -1 (at $x=1$).

Comment: @almagest  I requested clarification from the OP.  I even suggested that this was, perhaps, what they had in mind.  No response.  As such, I stand by my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint...

The range is restricted.  Hence the polynomial can't be an odd degree polynomial.  So make the coefficients of $x$ having odd powers equal to $0$ to find value of p.

Note - Don't make coefficient of $x$ as $0$ . Just set coefficients of $x^5$ and $x^3$ equal to zero, so that the polynomial immediately becomes even degreed.

Now you know the maximum value of quadratic so obtained.  Hence find the maximum value in terms of $q$ and set it equal to $-1$ to get possible values of $q$